# Send all email from *@example.com to user@example.com

Tags: email, dns

I dont know that I should ask this question here or at serverfault, so please migrate this if I am worng anyways.

It is such that if any person send an email to a random address ending with @example.com (My doamin here and not example.com) it always goes to user@example.com (again my domain here). We also know this kind of email as "Super Email".

Firstly, I want to try this first on a free domain such as co.cc or cu.cc (and later on the real .com domain), So I prefer a way that works with these.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is the job of whatever mail server is listed for the domain & handling its inbound mail; DNS is only involved in looking up the server, not users.

Comment: What if the Mail server is of Google Apps or Windows Live ? Or I need to setup another server that does this?

Comment: Look at how they handle *catch-all* addresses http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24070/catch-all-address-on-windows-live-domains

Comment: This means the Windows Live does not support this catch-all email address, but does Google Apps Does, if yes then How can I set it up.

Comment: just google for *google apps catch all*